# Customizable jquery mask

Tags: jquery, css

I've been playing with a masking function to allow users to type in numbers and it masks them out based on a certain pattern.

For example they type 123456789, but it appears in the field as XXX-XX-6789

Right now I have it hard coded to one pattern, but I would like to expand this to allow them to choose what ever pattern they wish. This is mainly if a client has a loyalty card or something along those lines. Is there a simple way of doing this without hard coding each pattern I think they may want?

My html

```
<p class="maskNum">
  <input type="text" class="form-control mask" autocomplete="off" maxlengthsocial="9" maxlength="11" />
  <input type="text" class="form-control maskval" autocomplete="off" maxlengthsocial="9" maxlength="9" />
</p>
```

my css

```
.maskNum {
  position: relative;
}

.maskval {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  color: transparent !important;
  background: transparent !important;
  border: none;
  left: 0;
  text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

my jquery

```
var pattern = 'xxx-xx-0000'

$('.maskval').on('keyup keydown change', function() {
  var res = this.value,
    len = res.length,
    max = 9,
    stars = len > 0 ? len > 1 ? len > 2 ? len > 3 ? len > 4 ? 'XXX-XX-' : 'XXX-X' : 'XXX-' : 'XX' : 'X' : '',
    result = stars + res.substring(5),
    truckResult = result.substring(0, 11);
  $(this).prev('input').val(truckResult).trigger('change');
});
```

and a fiddle that I made to test what I've built so far.
https://jsfiddle.net/5xwomLf7/8/

Comment: @AaronHall Spell check got me :)

Comment: Why are you using 2 inputs on top of each other?

Comment: @Adjit, it's so I can save the actual numbers that they enter securely into a database. If you look at the fiddle you can see how it works. I am just trying to branch it out and make it more robust to accept other patterns.

Comment: Well, with a carefully placed click I am put into the unmasked input. I would suggest either making that field hidden, or have an array that you `push` the key value into, that exists outside of the event function. Regardless I can't imagine there being any other way for you not to hardcode your mask, because how else would the program know where to put the dash? What would get even more complicated is if there were different mask setups for the same length of numbers.

Comment: @Adjit I do not have all my styles in the fiddle. So both of them are both the same height, width and such. I did not feel like that was the important part to put into the fiddle and spend the extra time on it. It is just a bare bones example. That is why I was trying to pass in the entire pattern including the dashes. So that the it knows what is supposed to go where. There has to be a possible solution.

Comment: What would be an example of another pattern you are trying to incorporate?

Comment: @Adjit I don't know. That would be up to the user to choose. We have an editor where the company we write this software for can choose how they want to use this. That is why I am trying to make it as dynamic as I can and so I'm not hard coding anything.

Comment: Oh, so like a CMS, and then you have the user say use `pattern = xxx-xx-xxx-0000`? So, you want the pattern to go based on the `pattern` string?

Comment: @Adjit Yes, so they can have any kind of card combination that is pertinent to their business.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your patterns are only going to contain numbers and x´s:

```
var pattern = 'x0x-0x-00x0'
$('.maskval').on('keyup keydown change', function() {
    var input = $(this).val();
    var output = "";

    for (var x=0; x<input.length; x++){
        if (x < pattern.length){
            output = pattern[x]=='x' ? output + 'x' :  output + input[x];        
        } else
            output += input[x];  // or nothing if you want the value to be only as long as the pattern
    }  

    if (input.length < pattern.length && pattern[input.length] == '-') {
        output += '-';
        $(this).val(output);
    } else {
        $(this).prev('input').val(output);
    }
});
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/5xwomLf7/15/ Nope, it just keeps replacing the first character. Type into the field on the right.

Comment: It seems like it's working with the combinations, however it seems to be ignoring the -'s

Comment: @zazvorniki - you do need to change the `maxlength` option do.

Comment: You know, didn't even thing about that. Yes, I guess I do